# Scheduling Tasks in Django

Tags: django, django-celery, django-cron

I am new to Django. I built a program that lets teachers assign homework to students. The homework has a due date that is different for each student.

I want to make it so that **1 hour before the homework is due** for that particular student, **they get sent an email**.

So, for example:

- Student 1 with HW **due at 3 pm** would get an **email at 2 pm**
- Student 2 with HW **due at 1 am** would get an **email at 12 am**

How can I achieve this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a Django Management command which identifies students who need to be sent a reminder email and then sends emails. use cron job(crontab in Linux) to run this Django management command periodically (every hour or every minute)

Comment: I see. Thanks so much for your response! How come you would recommend this over Celery?

Comment: Celery is excellent, I use it my self , but it has a steep learning for setting up tasks, also you will be need to use message broker to send tasks to celery and additional utility to run celery in daemon mode.

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice. By the way, I am running this on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Will Django Management Command work with that?

Comment: I have not used AWS Elastic Beanstalk before , but I am guessing the answer should be yes ,because cron jobs are part of basic functionality and i will be surprised if they are not supported.

Comment: Ok, while you're here. Could you link some good tutorials for this? I can't seem to find too many that have my use case. Or maybe even write an answer with code. Thanks!!

Comment: stack overflow is for asking for help , not for outsourcing your work to others.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to define a task or a list of tasks to be done.

Also you could use [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to schedule a task.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I've come across `Celery`, `django-background-tasks`, `django-cron`, `django-crontab` and many more. Do you know which one is best for this task? So far I've seen `Celery` be most recommended. Thanks!!

Comment: I think celery is the most useful however it's a bit complicated.